# Generic function for multiple generators in for comprehensions in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I want to create all possible combinations of letters "a" and "b". For combinations of length 2 using for-comprehensions it will be:

```scala
for {
   x <- Seq("a", "b") 
   y <- Seq("a", "b")
} yield x + y
```

And for combinations of length 3 it will be:

```scala
for {
   x <- Seq("a", "b") 
   y <- Seq("a", "b")
   z <- Seq("a", "b")
} yield x + y + z
```

Pretty similar. Is this possible to abstract this pattern and write generic function? 
I can think of such signature:

```scala
def genericCombine[A,B](length: Int, elements: Seq[A])(reducer: Seq[A] => B): Seq[B]
```

How can I parametrize number of generators used in for comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like permutations with replacement than combinations, and a recursive implementation is fairly straightforward:

```
def select(n: Int)(input: List[String]): List[String] =
  if (n == 1) input else for {
    c <- input
    s <- select(n - 1)(input)
  } yield c + s
```

Which works as expected:

```
scala> select(2)(List("a", "b"))
res0: List[String] = List(aa, ab, ba, bb)

scala> select(3)(List("a", "b"))
res1: List[String] = List(aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, bbb)
```

(You should of course check for invalid input in a real application.)

Comment: can it be made tail-recursive? :-}

Comment: Thanks Travis! Now it looks simple indeed

Comment: well, tail recursion or not, it does not really matter because the output size grows exponentially :)